# VB.net gravity simulation - having trouble with leaving trails behind planets

Tags: vb.net, graphics, simulation, physics

In my simulation, the planet's colour is randomly chosen when it is created. The trail left behind is supposed to be the same colour as its planet. This works fine if there is just one planet, but when a new planet is added the trail for every planet is the same colour as that of the new planet. Here are some screenshots to demonstrate what I mean:https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rLJe.jpg

I each planet to have a trail the same colour as itself, if that makes sense. Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
Public Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles picSpace.Paint
    For Each sun In sunsList
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Yellow, CInt(sun.positionX - 10), CInt(sun.positionY - 30), 20, 20)
    Next
    For Each planet In planetsList
        Dim planetFill As Brush = New SolidBrush(planet.colour)
        Dim trailColour As Pen = New Pen(planet.colour)
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(planetFill, planet.displayX - 5, planet.displayY - 5, 10, 10)
        For count As Integer = 0 To counter
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(trailColour, trail(0, count), trail(1, count), 1, 1)
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Sub Position()
    planet.displayX = Math.Round(planet.positionX)
    planet.displayY = Math.Round(planet.positionY)
    trail(0, counter) = planet.displayX
    trail(1, counter) = planet.displayY
    counter += 1
    ReDim Preserve trail(1, counter)
End Sub

Private Sub space_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles picSpace.Click
    If hsbSimulationSpeed.Value > 0 Then
        Timer1.Enabled = True
    End If
    If chkAddPlanets.Checked = True Then
        planet = New Body
        numberOfPlanets += 1
        planet.colour = GetRandomColour()
        planet.positionX = MousePosition.X
        planet.positionY = MousePosition.Y - 25
        planet.velocityX = txtVelocityX.Text * 1000
        planet.velocityY = txtVelocityY.Text * 1000
        planetsList.Add(planet)
    ElseIf chkAddSuns.Checked = True Then
        sun = New Body
        numberOfSuns += 1
        sun.positionX = MousePosition.X
        sun.positionY = MousePosition.Y
        sun.mass = hsbSunMass.Value * 5 * (10 ^ 29)
        sunsList.Add(sun)
    End If
End Sub

Function GetRandomColour() As Color
    Dim rand As New Random
    Return Color.FromArgb(rand.Next(0, 256), rand.Next(0, 256), rand.Next(0,
    256))
End Function
```

Is there an easy way to fix this, or will I need to completely change the way trails are generated?

Comment: I don't understand what the for loop does

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you only have 1 trail() list, which is used for all planets.  So in your painting loop, although the planet loop selects a different pen for each planet, they are all drawing in the same coordinates.  The last planet will overwrite the first ones.  Presumably trail() contains the coordinates from all planets - ie all trails listed together.

You need to have one trail list per planet, as part of the planet object to make it work.

Comment: trail() is a dynamic array, not a list. I tried to make it a property of planet, but visual studio says 'auto-implemented properties cannot have parameters'. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: trail needs to be within planet to get the logic for your system right.  _How_ is a different question, and you might need to ask another question if you get stuck.  For the error you had there are 2 obvious solutions: either remove the word `property` so that it is just a public variable within the planet class.  Or don't make it auto-implemented - fill in the `get` and `set` for it - if you get stuck with that best to ask a new question, or better: **search** since the same problem has almost certainly been asked already.